# populating drop down list to get Value field different from Text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net

I am trying to populate a DropDownList in the .NET framework, but I am having some trouble getting it formatted the way I want it to.

I'm grabbing the population members from a local database table called ZONE to be added into the drop down list. The Utils class was written to put the database table into a DataTable object. Here's exactly what I want it to do. I have two columns I want to read, DESCRIPTION and CODE. When I look at the drop down list, I want to see every DESCRIPTION entry. When I select the one I want, I then need the table to display the CODE column that corresponds with that DESCRIPTION into the field of my form. This is using the normal DropDownList class in the .NET framework. Here's the code I have below.

```
using (DataTable objDT = Utils.GetPopupList("ZONE", "ZONE"))
{
   ddlZONE.Items.Clear();
   ddlZONE.DataSource = objDT.Copy();
   ddlZONE.DataTextField = "DESCRIPTION";
   ddlZONE.DataValueField = "CODE";
   ddlZONE.DataTextFormatString = ddlSO_ZONE.DataTextField;
   ddlZONE.DataBind();
   ddlZONE.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(""));
}
```

The code I currently have displays the DESCRIPTION but also puts the DESCRIPTION into the field instead of the CODE value.

Does anyone know how I would tell my program to display the CODE instead after I select its DESCRIPTION?

Comment: what have you tried for this part of the problem "I then need the table to display the CODE column that corresponds with that DESCRIPTION into the field of my form."?

Comment: can you modify the query to be CODE + Description? ex: `SELECT (CODE + DESCRIPTION) as DESCRIPTION FROM ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On

> selected Index change

event of your dropdown list

you can simple set the form's control to show the value like this

```
lblCode.Text = ddlZONE.SelectedItem.Value;
```